# Clang and C++ Module TS

Tags: c++, module, clang

I have difficulty getting modules ts work on clang (both supplied with Xcode 9.3 beta and latest 7.0.0 trunk). I checked out other answers both here and on other platforms but I still can't figure it out. Here is what I have so far:

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
import stuff;

int main() {
  std::cout << whatever() << "\n";
}
```

### module.cppm

```
export module stuff;

export int whatever() {
  return 5;
}
```

Following various recommendations, I have done this:

```
clang -fmodules-ts -std=c++17 --precompile -o stuff.pcm module.cppm 
clang -fmodules-ts -std=c++17 -fmodule-file=stuff.pcm main.cpp
```

This results in linker error (`whatever() not found`). I am not sure how to proceed here.

Notes: I tried `-fprebuilt-module-path=.` instead of `-fmodule-file` and then it complains about unknown modules.

If someone can tell me how to set it up within Xcode, even better.

Disclaimer: I am not interested in a solution using module maps and traditional include. My interest in modules is not about improving compile times but about properly modularising my code (especially template code). Right now all my code is in header files anyway with the majority of functions declared as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one needs to compile the precompiled module file as well, either by compiling it to an object file and then linking that file, or via a shortcut:

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++17 -o main -fmodule-file=module.pcm  main.cpp module.pcm
```

I guess this makes some sense (if one sees modules as AST dumps, and hence just another kind of source file). I have also found out that one can use `-fprebuilt-module-path=.` option instead of specifying `-fmodule-file` if the name of the module and the name of the module file is the same.

That said, there are a lot of things that still confuse me. For instance, attributes such as `always_inline` or `noinline` don't seem to be honoured. The compiler will inline functions though when optimisation is on.